# License file doesnt work

Tags: license, licensing

I have EE 3.5.12 installation set up on Production server. I uploaded license key file but it seems system doesnt take this license into consideration.

It still says "The Core version of ExpressionEngine is feature limited. Upgrade today."

Any ideas appreaciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've installed the core version of Expression Engine. In this case,  download the commercial version and update your EE version.

The update docs link:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/upgrade_from_core.html